# Set-AzureVMDscExtension with large package leads to extreme memory usage in PowerShell DSC Extension

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, dsc

I finally managed to automate our release process using Desired State Configuration with the Azure PowerShell SDK methods, in particular the `Publish-AzureVMDscConfiguration -> Set-AzureVMDscExtension -> Update-AzureVM` combo.

After thinking for a while in [a way to send my build outputs somewhere accessible by the VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531301/how-do-i-transfer-my-build-output-files-to-an-azure-vm-using-powershell-dsc), I ended up with the strategy of appending my build drops in the configuration package that gets uploaded to Azure Storage.

My problem now is that as soon as the PowerShell DSC Extension in the VM starts downloading that package, it's memory consumption goes through the roof. When I open task manager, I can see the newly created PowerShell process going from 30 or so megabytes, to 300, and then to 1.3GB, completely ruining my VM.

Yesterday afternoon, I left work and let it processing, but when I logged into the VM today, the inner zip file, containing my build outputs, had 0 bytes in the DSCWork folder. My problem is that *even* if it worked in the end, it is taking a *very long* time and making my VM useless... I can't even change between windows in remote access, since the machine is completely stuck at 100% RAM usage.

Why is PowerShell taking so much memory and time to download my configuration package? It only has 60MB zipped, and roughly 200MB unzipped. Is there something I can do to prevent that from happening?

**UPDATE:**

I tested it just now and it finally finished correctly. Took more than a full hour, but the files are there... This is unacceptable though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue should be resolved in the next iteration of the extension. In the meanwhile you may want to consider uploading your build content to a blob separate from your configuration ZIP package (you can use Set-AzureStorageBlobContent for this).

Then you can use either the remote file or script resources in your original configuration to download the blob. Be sure to add the appropriate dependencies in your configuration so that the blob gets downloaded before you use it.

```
configuration DownloadSample
{
    Import-DscResource -Module xPSDesiredStateConfiguration

    xRemoteFile Download
    { 
       Uri = 'https://....blob.core.windows.net/windows-powershell-dsc/foo.zip?sv=...'
       DestinationPath = 'd:\tmp\download.zip'
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "should be resolved in the next iteration of the extension"? Is it a known issue? If you could share a link to it I'd really appreciate it. I took a look at the extension scripts and found nothing that could lead to such crazy memory usage. I'll consider that approach, but I'd like to avoid it since this same configuration is used on a on premise machine, where I can access the file share where the drops are directly.

Comment: The issue in the current scripts is that they download the content to memory and then use Set-Content to write it to disk. This can be hugely expensive for large files and has been fixed. There will be another release of the extension later this month and the fix is included there.

Comment: Do you have a quick suggestion until the fix is not live? I have access to the VM and I know where the scripts are. If you could point me at the fix, I could probably replicate it and save those scripts right?

Comment: This is amazing! I hand edited the `Get-AzureBlobContent` cmdlet on the `DscExtensionUtilities.psm1` module to use the `OutFile` parameter of `Invoke-WebRequest`, thus saving the contents directly instead of using the piped `Set-Content`, and the process now only consumes 150MB at most, and finishes very quickly! This will do just fine until the new version releases.

Comment: Just wanted to put this here in case it helps anyone. After installing the version 1.5.0.0 of the extension, the problem is gone.